# How to exclude folder using rsync inside root?

Tags: rsync

I have got a `rsync` task and want to exclude my `./js/` folder. Because of that I use:

```
--exclude js
```

What happens now is that not only the `./js/` folder, but although the `./assets/js/` folder will not be synced. How can I tell rsync to only exclude the folder inside my root document?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tie the directory name to the top of the tree. This is explained in the `rsync` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) under the section *FILTER RULES*.

> If the pattern starts with a `/` then it is anchored to a particular spot in the hierarchy of files, otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname.

So you need to use `/js`, for example like this:

```
rsync -av --exclude /js {src} {dst}
```